# Angular Moment - Change Locale with customized locale object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm having issues configuring a locale change in my Angular app. I'm using [Angular Moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) and Moment.js

First, I'm setting the locale to english in my angular.module.config and immediately setting the relative time object as I need:

```
            moment.locale('en', {
                relativeTime: {
                    future: "In %s",
                    past: "%s ago",
                    s: "<1 minute",
                    m: "1 minute",
                    mm: "%d minutes",
                    h: "1 hour",
                    hh: "%d hours",
                    d: "24 hours",
                    dd: "%d days",
                    M: "1 month",
                    MM: "%d months",
                    y: "1 year",
                    yy: "%d years"
                }
            });
```

This works as intended,

Now I also have an equal object but for german. I don't know where to drop it because if I drop it in the config it overrides the english config.

Then I have a select dropdown in a header menu view with EN and DE (I'm already getting it to lower case for translations) in my controller and I can't seem to associate the `amMoment.changeLocale('de');` to change the moment part to german, and I can't seem to update it with moment directly as well.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize `relativeTime` for multiple locale in succession without overriding the previous configuration.

You can use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to bind the dropdown change to a function that calls `amMoment.changeLocale` for the selected locale.

Note that you have to import `moment-with-locales` or all required locale files in order to use moment with non-default locales.

If I understood what you want to accomplish, here there is a working example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.run(function(){
  moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime: {
      future: "In %s",
      past: "%s ago",
      s: "<1 minute",
      m: "1 minute",
      mm: "%d minutes",
      h: "1 hour",
      hh: "%d hours",
      d: "24 hours",
      dd: "%d days",
      M: "1 month",
      MM: "%d months",
      y: "1 year",
      yy: "%d years"
    }
  });
  moment.updateLocale('de', {
    relativeTime: {
      future : 'in %s',
      past : 'vor %s',
      s : '<ein Minute',
      m : 'ein Minute',
      mm : '%d Minuten'
    }
  });
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, moment, amMoment) {
  $scope.last_update = moment().valueOf();
  $scope.lang = 'en';
  
  $scope.changeLang = function(){
    amMoment.changeLocale($scope.lang);
  };
  $scope.changeLang();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/0.10.3/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  {{last_update|amDateFormat:'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss a'}}
  <br/>
  <span am-time-ago="last_update"></span>
  <br/>
  
  <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="lang" ng-change="changeLang()">
    <option value="en">EN</option>
    <option value="de">DE</option>
  </select>
  
  {{lang}}
  
</div>
```